# CSS Beginner troubles with hover

Tags: css

I'm been learning for web design as well as development for quite some time now but I'm still stumped by some basic rules of CSS.

I'm trying to figure out how the behavior of :hover works when hovering one element, to affect another. But I came across something unexpected...

Q: Why does element .one turn black when .two is hovered?

Here's the code and the fiddle.

HTML:

```
<div class="one">

    <div class="two"></div>    

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}

.one {
    left:0;
    background: red;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

.two {
    left:200px;
    background: yellow;
}

.one:hover {
    background: black;
}
```

[here is my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GR9ZK/1/)

Help anyone?

Comment: Because two is a child of one.

Comment: You probably wanted something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GR9ZK/2/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element `.two` is found inside the `.one` element. so hovering `.two` means that you are also hovering `.one`. The event "bubbles" up to the parent element.. even if it doesn't look like that visually. To hover each one independently you will have to take `.two` out of `.one`. You might want to wrap both in a container to properly set their positioning. [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GR9ZK/3/)

```
<div class="someContainer">    
    <div class="one"></div>   
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your html structure to achieve this.
As right now div having class two is inside the div class one so two is becoming child of class one div so when you hover on div which have class two it automatics consider that you are hovring on class one div as well.
Use absolute div and don't make it child of class one div.